# Firebase httpsCallable returns error from React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So when I open functions in my firebase console. I open the function's link which is https://us-central1-geochatterthing.cloudfunctions.net/getWall .
And this link gets opened into a browser with below error

> {"error":{"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Bad Request"}}

Also, my scenario is that there is an app already on Google Play on which images are being fetched using the function `getWall`. And now I'm supposed to redesign the app using the same original code.

But now the `getWall`function doesn't seems to work.

`const wallFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall');`

`result = await wallFunc({size: 15});`

Can someone please tell me what could be the issue here? 
Thanks in advance! :)

UPDATE:

Below is the code for the `getWall` function I accessed from Google Cloud Console.

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _messages = require("./messages");

Object.keys(_messages).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _messages[key];
    }
  });
});

var _conversations = require("./conversations");

Object.keys(_conversations).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _conversations[key];
    }
  });
});

var _profiles = require("./profiles");

Object.keys(_profiles).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _profiles[key];
    }
  });
});

var _auth = require("./auth");

Object.keys(_auth).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _auth[key];
    }
  });
});

var _apiHttp = require("./api-http");

Object.keys(_apiHttp).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _apiHttp[key];
    }
  });
});

var _friends = require("./friends");

Object.keys(_friends).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _friends[key];
    }
  });
});

var _wall = require("./wall");

Object.keys(_wall).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _wall[key];
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the code of your `getWall` Cloud Function ? You may be mixing up HTTP Cloud Functions and Callable Cloud Functions but it is not 100% clear... You should give more details on how is coded the Cloud Function and how do you call it (through an URL or via `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall');`?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I access the code for `getWall` cloud function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534966/cloud-functions-for-firebase-retrieving-already-deployed-code/52535292#52535292

Comment: maybe that is because of registrationToken , see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141865/7858922)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec please check my updated question. I've now added the code of `getWall` cloud function.

Comment: @ShubhamBisht Actually, this code does not seem to be Cloud Functions for Firebase code.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So where can I access the right code?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I use this `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall')`

Comment: I have no idea! If this is the code you got by exactly following the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534966/cloud-functions-for-firebase-retrieving-already-deployed-code/52535292#52535292, I am sorry but I cannot help you further as this is not Cloud Functions for Firebase code IMO and I don't know what is this code doing.

Comment: Using firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall') means that you call a Callable Cloud Function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable and the code you shown is not corresponding to a Callable Cloud Function... What else can I say?! :)

Comment: @ShubhamBisht i understand, and i am explaining that "this is not Cloud Functions for Firebase code IMO and I don't know what is this code doing". You should contact the persons who wrote this code.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec should I need to deploy the callable function in my App? I'm not sure if it has already been deployed or not.

Comment: The Callable Cloud Function shall be deployed on the Firebase platform (Google Cloud Platform), not on your app. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: @RenaudTarnec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001098/how-to-search-documents-from-a-collection-based-on-a-field-in-firestore-databa can you please check this question?