# How to search document(s) from a collection based on a Field in Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a React Native application and I'm fetching profiles from a firebase collection.
And I want to add a search functionality where when I enter even the first 1 or 2 (or more) alphabets of a username and press the search button.
I should be able to fetch usernames starting with those 1 or 2 alphabets.

I did check Cloud Firestore queries but couldn't find one for my problem.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

[image]

In the above code, I'm adding the below code as answered by Renaud Tarnec.

```
 let queries = hashes.map(hash => rangeQueryParams(hash))
            .map(range => profiles.where('hash', '>=', range.start).where('hash', '<', range.end)
            .orderBy('displayName') // displayName is the name of Field here
            .startAt(searchString)
            .endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff')
            .get());
```

But this doesn't seems to work. I guess it's because range filter and `orderBy` are on different fields here.

Comment: you'll need to fetch the whole document which contains usernames and perform a query locally.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani No I actually want to fetch all the fields including username for every document

Answer (score 8):

You should use a combination of `orderBy()`, `startAt()` and `endAt()`, see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=0

```
 var searchString = 'Sh'   //Example of value
 firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('yourCollectioName')
      .orderBy('username')
      .startAt(searchString)
      .endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff')
      .get()
  .then(...)
```

The character `\uf8ff` used in the query is after most regular characters in Unicode, therefore the query matches all values that start with `searchString`.

Comment: what is '\uf8ff' here?

Comment: Thank you. :) If you don't mind can you please look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for full text search recommended by Firebase is to use Algolia https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Using Firestore’s queries with start at and end at with an ordered collection certainly work. If you have a need for full text search within your app elsewhere that requires spelling tolerance etc for example then moving to Algolia is worth considering instead of using compound firestore queries

Comment: This is considering exact match. How to remove capitalization in search a string. So that i can search any letter even if it capital or small will get result. Also how can i check if string available in the name in between like 

name is puneet

and if i search neet then it will also show the result.